# Xor encryption in C++ with warning "Use of a signed integer operand with a binary bitwise operator"

Tags: c++, encryption, compiler-warnings, xor

I'm learning the simple XOR encryption algorithm in c++.

The next code works fine:

```
void test(int8_t* data, const int data_length) {
    const uint8_t key = 123;

    for (int index = 0; index < data_length; index++)
        data[index] = data[index] ^ key;
}
```

The **data** that I am given is signed, therefore has a type of **int8_t**.

The problem is that the compiler shows the next warning:

> "Use of a signed integer operand with a binary bitwise operator”

I can make the warning go by casting **data** with **uint8_t** when performing the XOR operation, but I don't know the implications. I've done some test and doesn't seem to be a problem, but I am confused because data can contain signed values, so I am not sure if by casting it I am messing the data.

Is it correct to cast to uint8_t even if data can contain negative values? or should I ignore the warning?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - can you tell us which compiler you are using? I have tried with a couple (MSVC and clang-cl) and they don't generate such a warning.

Comment: @AdrianMole it completely depends on your warning level; GCC, clang and MSVC will provide such a warning if you configure your compiler to do so.

Comment: I am using clang using CLion from IntelliJ

Comment: @FabianKeßler I have /Wall (all warnings enabled) in MSVC (VS-2019) and no warning is given: neither in compilation nor static analysis. However, I can see that there *should* be a warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is giving the warning because bitwise operations are not supposed to be performed on signed integers. In C++ before C++20, there were allowed different representations of signed integers, meaning that the same number could be represented by different bit patterns on different machines and compilers. This makes the result of bit manipulations on signed integers non-portable. Granted, `intN_t` were always required to use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation (and C++20 extended that requirement to all signed integers), it is still not recommended to use signed integers for bitwise operations.

In your particular case, both `data[index]` and `key` get promoted to `int` to perform the XOR operation. However, since `data[index]` is a signed integer, its value gets sign-extended, and the unsigned `key` gets zero-extended. This means the XOR affects only the low 8 bits of the intermediate `int` values, and the result may not fit in `int8_t` range. When you assign the result back to `data[index]`, a signed overflow can happen, which is UB in C++ (prior to C++20; since C++20 it is well defined to truncate the upper bits).

The correct thing to do in this case is to treat your data as an array of raw bytes, regardless of what values these bytes represent. This means, you should be using [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) or `std::uint8_t` to represent input and output data. This way you will be operating on unsigned integers and have no portability or potential overflow issues.

Answer (score 1):

With c++20, you should use a bitwise copy:

```
void test(int8_t* data, const int data_length) {
    const uint8_t key = 123;

    for (int index = 0; index < data_length; index++){
        auto const encrypted = std::bit_cast<std::byte>(data[index]) ^ key;
        data[index] = std::bit_cast<int8_t>(encrypted);
    }
}
```

For previous versions you should static_cast the signed type to the corresponding unsigned type.

```
void test(int8_t* data, const int data_length) {
    const uint8_t key = 123;

    for (int index = 0; index < data_length; index++){
        auto const encrypted = static_cast<std::byte>(data[index]) ^ key;
        data[index] = static_cast<int8_t>(encrypted);
    }
}
```

Comment: No `std::` before `static_cast`. Also, you might want to consistently use `std::` qualification with `int8_t` and other types or omit it.

Comment: Corrected that, but std::byte is not in the global namespace, int8_t and uint8_t in particular is.

Comment: `int8_t` and `uint8_t` are not in the global namespace in my clang compiler.  Of course, I can add them there by doing `using std::int8_t;` and `using std::uint8_t;`.  Or by doing `#include <stdint.h>`.

Comment: @FabianKeßler C++ defines `int8_t`, as other standard types, in `std` namespace. You see it in the global namespace from your C includes, which many C++ implementations use internally. That global name is not standard, though, and is present by accident.

Comment: @Eljay depends on the headers you include. intX_t and uintX_t are parts of the old c-api and including <cstdint> will include stdint-uintn.h (with clang-13 and libstdc++) . And there uint8_t is defined in the global namespace.

Comment: Could you please explain the reason of static_cast<std::byte>? Maybe I got wrong but isn't srd::byte an alias of "unsigned char"? I am trying to understand why if data is signed and can contain signed values, then why if I cast it to unsigned it doesn't produce incorrect results.

Comment: @API_1024 no, std::byte is defined as enum with unsigned char as underlying type. All numeric operations are forbidden, only bitwise operations are allowed.
It is the ["modern"](http://www.nuonsoft.com/blog/2018/06/03/c17-stdbyte/) way to express that you are working with raw data.

Comment: @API_1024 `std::byte` is not an alias, it is a separate type, which has the same size as `unsigned char`. Casting to `std::byte` does not change bit representation of the value, but it changes its interpretation. Since you only operate on bit representation anyway using XOR, the result is the same (sans sign/zero extension mentioned in my answer).